# Generate square sub-matrices of 1's

Tags: code-golf, matrix

Back again, stealing another question from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58516692/6301103).

You are given a list of integers >= 0. Generate in order square 1-matrices where the side length is given by the list entry of the current index and fill the rest with 0s.

So given a list 2,4,1,3 print this to stdout:

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

## Rules

- Efficiency doesn't matter. (as long as it terminates on e.g. TIO)
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- In/Output has to adhere to the [default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) consensus.
- This is code-golf. Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: A nice question, but a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, that one wouldn't pop up when I searched for duplicates.